# Issue regarding binding a javascript event with a innerHTML DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Right now I am facing a serious problem regarding how to bind javascript event to an innerHTML DOM element. I have a div and there is an input checkbox in that div and some javascript event is already bound to that checkbox. I have another div and some text is written over there. Now through javascript I need to create a div and the content of the newly created div will be the content of the other two existing divs and the javscript event will be intact for the checkbox when it will be copied and placed to the newly created div.

I have successfully done all these except one thing. When I am placing checkbox from previous div to the newly created div by using innerHTML, it is being placed without the javascript event bound with it.

My HTML structure is as follows:

```
<div id="text_holder">
"Lubricant"
<input type="checkbox" id="Lubricantc" class="check_class">
</div>

<div id="text_holder2">
SKF,FAG
</div>
```

text_holder and text_holder2 are my two existing div.

Now the javascript code for creating another div and copying the data from these two previous divs and placing it there in the new div is:

```
var previous_ig_content=document.getElementById("text_holder");
var previous_brand_content=document.getElementById("text_holder2");
var child_div=document.createElement('div');
child_div.id=ig_id+"div";
child_div.innerHTML=previous_ig_content.innerHTML+previous_brand_content.innerHTML;
```

I have done a lot of research to resolve this. But did not work out properly.
Please help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance!!!

My full javascript is as follows:-

```
function removepersist(event)
{
    console.log("in removepersist");

    var pa=$(event.target).closest("div").prop("id");
    var pa_data=$(event.target).closest("div").prop("id");
    var grandparent=$('#'+pa).parent().prop("id");

    var inner_data=document.getElementById(pa).innerHTML;

    if (grandparent=='persist')
    {


      document.getElementById('text_holder').innerHTML=pa_data.replace('div','')+"   ";
      var ig_id=event.target.id.slice(0,-1);
      var check=document.createElement('input');
      check.type='checkbox';
      check.id=event.target.id;
      check.className="check_class";
      check.onclick=function()
      {
        checkwork(ig_id,event);
      }

      document.getElementById('text_holder').appendChild(check);
      var holder2_unused=inner_data.substr(0, inner_data.indexOf(':')); 
      var holder2_actual=inner_data.replace(holder2_unused,'');
      document.getElementById("text_holder2").innerHTML=holder2_actual;

      $("#persist :input").attr("disabled", true);

     var unused_part=inner_data.substring(inner_data.lastIndexOf("<"),inner_data.lastIndexOf(":")+1);
     var reqd_data=inner_data.split(unused_part);
     var item_group_name=reqd_data[0];
     var brands_names=reqd_data[1].split(',')

     for (i=0;i<brands_names.length;i++)
     {
      if(brands_names[i].includes("(AD)"))
      {
        new_brand_name=brands_names[i].replace('(AD)','')
        $(".brand_tag[value="+new_brand_name+"]").attr("checked", true);
        $(".dealer_tag[value="+new_brand_name+"]").attr("checked", true);
      }
      else
      {
        new_brand_name=brands_names[i]
        console.log("- - - - -");
        console.log(""+brands_names[i]+"jigsaw");
        //$(".brand_tag[value="+new_brand_name+"]").prop("checked", true);
        //$("input[name=brand_id[]][value="+new_brand_name+"]").attr('checked', 'checked');
        console.log("++++++");

      }
     }


    }

    var to_be_removed=document.getElementById(pa);
    to_be_removed.parentNode.removeChild(to_be_removed);
}
function checkwork(ig_id,event)
{
  console.log("in checkwork for : "+ig_id+" and "+event.target.id);

  var previous_ig_content=document.getElementById("text_holder");
  var previous_brand_content=document.getElementById("text_holder2");
  var child_div=document.createElement('div');
  child_div.id=ig_id+"div";
  child_div.innerHTML=previous_ig_content.innerHTML+previous_brand_content.innerHTML;


  document.getElementById('persist').appendChild(child_div);

  $("#persist :input").attr("disabled", false);
  $("#persist :input").attr("checked", true);

  $('.itemgroup_tag').prop('checked',false);
  $('.brand_tag').prop('checked',false);
  $('.dealer_tag').prop('checked',false);


  document.getElementById('text_holder').innerHTML="";
  document.getElementById('text_holder2').innerHTML="";

}

$('.check_class').click(function() {                                //This is for the existing checkbox in persist
    console.log("by existing check");
    removepersist(event);

});




$(".itemgroup_tag").click(function() {

document.getElementById('text_holder').innerHTML=$(this).prop('value')+"   ";
var ig_id=$(this).prop('value');
var check=document.createElement('input');
check.type='checkbox';
check.id=$(this).prop('value')+"c";
check.className="check_class";
check.onclick=function () {            //this part is for appending the content of text_holder and text_holder2 to persist 

   checkwork(ig_id,event); 
}

 document.getElementById('text_holder').appendChild(check);
});
```

Comment: You know that `.innerHTML` overwrites everything that it's assigned to, right?

Comment: Yeah,but is this a matter of overwriting? I dont know. If it does not then how to fix my problem.

Comment: What is `ig_id` ? It's not defined , plus the `child_div` needs to be appended to the DOM sometime after creation.

Comment: can you add your full javascript code

Comment: @Abhradip when and if you return, please ensure that you provide a [mcve] . That shouldn't be a problem since you have it mostly working already and don't forget to include that event that's disappearing as well, because I don't see one at the moment.

Comment: I know that the child_div needs to be appended somewhere. I have done already these thing successfully. This is causing no problem. Thats why I omitted that part here. @zer00ne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Here I replaced the checkbox with a button, which responds to click. you can simply replace it with checkbox.

```js
function checkFunc(){
    var previous_ig_content=document.getElementById("text_holder").innerHTML;
  var previous_brand_content=document.getElementById("text_holder2").innerHTML;
  var childDiv = document.createElement('div');
  childDiv.id="newDiv";
 childDiv.onclick =alertMess;
 childDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";
 childDiv.style.cursor = "pointer";   childDiv.innerHTML=previous_ig_content+previous_brand_content;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(childDiv);
}

function alertMess(){
  alert("oh! you clicked the generated div");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text_holder">
"Lubricant"
<!-- <input type="checkbox" id="Lubricantc" class="check_class" ></input> -->
<button onclick="checkFunc()">Click me</button>
</div>
<div id="text_holder2">
SKF,FAG
</div>
```

Comment: I used checkbox and the fact is that the checkbox was also created by javascript and the event was bound then. I think that is causing problem. The checkbox is not there actually on DOM. It is was created by some javascript.

Comment: ok.. but you can add an click event to it, where it was generated. like if we were to attach an onclick event on the generated div in this example : `childDiv.onclick="newFunction()"`

Comment: I'm gonna edit my answer and show this to you . give me five

Comment: see it now. I attached a click event on the generated div when you click on it. If this solves your problem can you please accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: You have written a line as childDiv.onclick =alertMess; and it is working fine. Now if I need to send some parameter to alertMess function then how to write it? should it be like childDiv.onclick =alertMess(x,y) or anything else

Comment: yes. I haven't tried that before because I was only triggering event but it looks right. let me know if any issue comes up, I'll be happy to help

Comment: No, there is no issue. I have just implemented that approach and its working fine. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Using native javascript there you can use `innerHTML` or [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) - but they clone only the *inline* listeners and not those using `addEventListener` - see demo below:

```js
// checkbox listener
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log("clicked");
});

// clone and append
document.body.appendChild(document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper')[0].cloneNode(true));

// inline listener
function inline() {
  console.log("inline");
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Yes / No</span>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="inline()" />
</div>
```

**Solution**

If you would use Jquery, you have a solution - it has a [`clone()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_clone.asp) method - *clone(true)* directs it to copy event handlers too! See a demo below:

```js
$(function() {
  // checkbox listener
  $('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function() {
    console.log("clicked");
  });
  // clone and append
  $('body').append($('.wrapper').clone(true));
});

// inline listener
function inline() {
  console.log("inline");
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Yes / No</span>
  <input type="checkbox" onclick="inline()" />
</div>
```